# How to convert Windows Phone Living Image to Live Photo?

Tags: icloud, photos

I am in the process of porting all my media to iCloud so it’s easily accessible via my iPhone and iPad.  I used to have a Windows Phone, which took essentially the same thing as Live Photos but were called Living Images.  I’d like to move these to iCloud and have them show up as Live Photos.

I used a Lumia 830 with Windows Phone 8.1, and the Living Images essentially had a .jpg for the photo and a .mp4 which contained the 0.6s video just prior to the photo.  I tried copying the .jpg and .mp4 to iCloud, and while they showed up, the showed up as two separate files.  I then used ffmpeg to move the video to a mov container, and copied that over, which also showed up as a separate file.

**What is iCloud/iOS looking for to associate a .jpg and .mov as a Live Photo?**

It doesn’t seem to be the same base name plus .jpg/.mov.  Perhaps some metadata in either or both of the files?  Do the videos need to be some exact encoding? (Both the Live Photos and Living Images used AVC for the video codec).

Are there any Apple documents that detail Live Photos?

Here’s a link to some technical details about Living Photos:
https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/12159

Edit:
I found some more information.  First, a blog post from Cellebrite (yeah, that Cellebrite...) led me to some more info.
https://www.cellebrite.com/en/blog/how-to-confirm-apple-live-photos-in-cellebrite-blacklight/

This pointed me to the ContentIdentifier field in the metadata, which is a matching UUID for the .jpg/.mov pair.

And this led to a few more links:
https://github.com/LimitPoint/LivePhoto
https://www.limit-point.com/blog/2018/live-photos/

I am going to try using exiftool to try to write a UUID to the proper metadata tags to see if I can get this to work.

I'm still a bit unsure if the slight video encoding differences will matter, and the docs above say that there should be a timestamp in the metadata for where in the video the still is located.  In living images that I have, the video is just prior to the still image, which is different to real living photos. I'm not sure that timestamp matters all that much unless you're editing a live photo.

Comment: See https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-living-images-photos-app-windows-10-creators-update

Comment: @Allan, thanks for the link, though I think you may have misunderstood.  I've already got a bunch of living images that I want to convert into live photos, so that when I upload them to iCloud, they behave just like any native live photo I've taken with my iPhone.

Comment: I understand, but Living Photos was a Lumia product that Microsoft adapted.  Nobody else supported the format.  Consequently, there aren't any "Living Photo" to "Live Photo" conversion utilities nor is it a format macOS recognizes.  You need to export it from the Photos App (Microsoft)  as a video or series of images and make an animated GIF.  I don't know of anything that takes an animated GIF and converts it to a live image (Mac).